# Passing NSArray to Detail View using Plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm currently using the following plist to create a drill down table view. However, I'm having problems passing the array of children over to the DetailViewController.

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Food</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Food</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>Description about Food.</string>
            <key>IconLink</key>
            <string>WFImage.png</string>
            <key>Children</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>ChildName</key>
                    <string>Burgers</string>
                    <key>ChildDescription</key>
                    <string>Description of Burgers</string>
                    <key>ChildIconLink</key>
                    <string>WFImage.png</string>
                    <key>ChildImageLink</key>
                    <string>WFBanner.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>ChildName</key>
                    <string>Hot Dogs</string>
                    <key>ChildDescription</key>
                    <string>Description of Hot Dogs</string>
                    <key>ChildIconLink</key>
                    <string>WFImage.png</string>
                    <key>ChildImageLink</key>
                    <string>WFBanner.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
```

Using the following I was able to pass down the array of children to my detail view (correct amount of rows will show), but I'm not able to extract any children elements.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showMenuDetail"]) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.menuTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            HomeDetailViewController *HDViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
            HDViewController.foodChildren = [[menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Children"];
            HDViewController.foodName = [[menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Name"];

            NSLog(@"Food Children: %@", HDViewController.foodChildren);
    }

}
```

When I try the following in the detail view's cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
children = [foodChildren objectForKey:@"ChildName"];
cell.textLabel.text = [children objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I get the following error:

> reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x200a7870'

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: children = [infectionChildren objectForKey:@"ChildName"]; Does the log print the proper output for children?

Comment: infectionChildren is an array.  But you use it like a dictionary.  That was what the error message telling you.

Comment: my bad everyone it's foodChildren not infectionChildren (Switched it).  But yes Dana0550, it prints out properly but in the my root view controller. It never gets a chance to log it in the detail view because it crashes.

Comment: Read our lips:  The message is saying that you're attempting to do an `objectForKey` on an array.  (And it doesn't like that.)

Comment: Read the plist:  The outer level is a dict.  The "Food" element of that is an array.  The elements of "Food" are dicts.  The "Children" element of one of those dicts is an array.  That array contains dicts.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `infectionChildren` is an `NSArray` (probably got with `[yourPlist objectForKey:@"Children"]`, though I don't see that in the code you posted).  If `infectionChildren` is an array of NSDictionaries then you can't just use `[infectionChildren objectForKey:@"ChildName"]` because `NSArray` doesn't respond to objectForKey.

You should iterate over your array to extract the child names, like:

```
NSMutableArray *children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[infectionChildren count]];
for (NSDictionary *childDictionary in infectionChildren) {
    [children addObject:[childDictionary objectForKey:@"ChildName"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because it seems like you are trying to send the "objectForKey" message to an NSArray.

According to your plist setup and code, **HDViewController.foodChildren** is an Array so my question is how are you passing that into the variable "**infectionChildren**"?

You should be parsing the objects in the **HDViewController.foodChildren** NSArray into **infectionChildren** in the

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

NSDictionary *infectionChildren = [self.foodChildren objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 

}
```

Comment: Hey @iamraymondchen Oops! infectionChildren was actually foodChildren, I forgot to change it in the code. also foodChildren is an NSDictionary, so objectAtIndex: doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are **using NSDictionary method over an NSArray**. **objectForKey:** is used for the dictionary but infectionChildren you are using is an Array.

Hope it helps you.